# Missing authData of parse user

Tags: android, parse-platform, twitter-util

I' m having bit of a problem with parse android library. Auth data of the users is missing in results of query. Therefore ParseTwitterUtils can't tell if the user is linked or not.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In case anyone needs help with this, after reading through old parse community forum i found a similar question https://parse.com/questions/cant-access-authdata-on-the-user-object-cloud-code 
. The answer given there by Hector(Parser) is : 
**try issuing a fetch() on the user; this should populate the authData field.**

Answer (score 0):

authData contains sensitive information about the Parse.User so the only way you can get it is if the user object is retrieved by login (user logs in and session token is valid) or by using the Master Key when doing the query.